# How to apply concurrency check for tables using EF Core in ABP Framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, abp

please help me with the following -
I am using ABP Framework version 5.3 along with .Net version 6.
There are around 3 tables in my system, let’s say Table-R-1, Table-R-2, and Table-W-1. My database is Microsoft SQL Server and these tables are interrelated but there is no explicit foreign key relationship . How can I make sure that when we try to update(Edit/Insert/Delete)  Table-W-1, related records in Table-R-1 and Table-R-2 do not get modified?

What if we read related records from Table-R-1 and Table-R-2 within the same scope within which I am updating Table-W-1? Would that make sure that if any changes happen in Table-R-1 and Table-R-2 then a db concurrency exception would be thrown and my write changes would not be committed?